# Transmission php class (How to get info of torrent)

Tags: php, arrays, class, multidimensional-array, transmission-daemon

I'm using the php transmission rpc class (https://github.com/brycied00d/PHP-Transmission-Class) to retrieve torrent info. But I don't know how to retrieve data from an array object (level 5).
I retrieve data like 
`$torrent_name = $result['arguments']['torrents'][0]['name'];`

The Info I want is like :

```
$torrent_client_name = $result['arguments']['torrents'][0]['peers']['clientName'];
```

and here is the function,

```
 public function get ( $ids = array(), $fields = array() )
    {
    if ( !is_array( $ids ) ) $ids = array( $ids );
        if ( count( $fields ) == 0 ) $fields = array( "id", "name"); //this array
    $request = array(
    "fields" => $fields,
    "ids" => $ids
    );
    return $this->request( "torrent-get", $request );
    }
```

I tried to make something like this but no result:

`$fields = array( "id", "name", array("peers"=>"clientName"));`

or

`$fields = array( "id", "name", array("clientName"));`

or

`$fields = array( "id", "name", 'peers' => array('clientName'));`

The error I get :

> Notice: Undefined index: peers

[and here the var_dump($result);](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsYf8.png)

Comment: Can you edit your question and paste the contents of `var_dump($result);`?

Comment: Yup I added it :) and I the documentation https://trac.transmissionbt.com/browser/trunk/extras/rpc-spec.txt

Comment: I don't see the var dump

Comment: Well you can get it here https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsYf8.png it's a screen

Comment: I don't see `peers` or `client name` in that array, so you aren't going to be able to get those values1

Comment: Yes I know that, the problem is that i don't know how to declare them in the function. You can see the documentation of the librairy (https://trac.transmissionbt.com/browser/trunk/extras/rpc-spec.txt). Thanks you for your answers